# Split two digit numbers

Tags: c, floating-point, decimal

I try to split any number of two digits and get result in two different variables. I had a problem with a specific number: `23`.

```
int root = 23;
float div = (float)root/10.0; // div = 23.0/10.0 = 2.3

int left = (int)div; // left = 2
int right = ((float)div - (float)left) * 10.0; // right = (2.3 - 2) * 10.0 = 0.3 * 10.0 = 3

printf("%d", right); // 2, why ?
```

There is a lot of float-to-int operations and I got some troubles with the final result. Have I miss or didn't catch something ?

Comment: OMG, `a = root / 10; b = root % 10;`

Comment: I slightly remember that i have had a simmilar problem wich was solved by also converting the second number as 10.0 is sometimes interpreted as an int - so try rewriting: `float div = (float)root/(float)10.0; // div = 23.0/10.0 = 2.3`

Comment: As an aside note - it is usually best to avoid floats as they are not precise

Comment: @pytomaniaq you are remembering a different problem. The issue here is not an integer division being applied where the programmer intended a floating-point one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since 0.3 may not be represented exactly in binary, you end up with 2.9999… that became `2` when converted to an `int`.

Instead:

```
int root = 23;
int left = root / 10;
int right = root % 10;
```

Comment: That's the explanation I wanted to have. `%` is the solution therefore. Thanks !